# Why are there headphones with frequencies beyond humans can hear?

Tags: audio, headphones, frequency-response

For example Sennheiser HD 800 has `6 to 51,000 Hz` but humans can only hear `20 to 20,000 Hz`. Is there a benefit in terms of sound quality to humans if they listen to something they can't hear?

Comment: http://sound.stackexchange.com/questions/22102/what-is-the-point-of-a-frequency-response-higher-than-20-hz-to-20-khz?rq=1